# Compatible truncation of series

Tags: real-analysis

Is it analytically possible to  find required number of truncation terms $n$ ( or real $n$ if that is not possible ) from truncated sine/cosine series for a given positive integer $m$  satisfying trig identity:

$$ \sin^2(x,n) +\cos^2(x,m) =1 \, $$

.. so that there should be no truncation error? Can such an analytical function be defined? When $(m,n) $ go to $\infty$ we have the regular series trig definition.

Comment: What makes you think that this is possible ? There are no polynomials such that $p^2(x)+q^2(x)=1$.

Comment: And what do you mean by "real $n$" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These trigonometric series are alternating so that the remainder is of the same order as the last term. So the truncation errors will be "compatible" for $n=m\pm1$. But of course, the one cannot compensate the other.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at some sort of "exact" compensation if it can be defined in any manner.

Comment: @Narasimham: did you read my comments ?